# Unable to read holding register PLC usign Pymodbus serial

Tags: serial-port, plc, pymodbus

I am trying to read a holding register on my PLC suning pymodbus

I connected to my PLC using serial RS232 through com port 5

```
client = ModbusClient(method='rtu', port='com5', timeout=1,baudrate=9600)

client.connect()
Out[8]: True


client.read_holding_registers(00x00,1,unit=1)

pymodbus.exceptions.ModbusIOException('No Response received from the remote unit/Unable to decode response', 3)
```

[PLC MODBUS ADDRESS SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbtrj.png)

Getting following error

What am i doing wrong?

Please help

Comment: Is there a connection? Can you confirm that the connection has been established?

Comment: If this is on Windows, also try `strict=False`  in client initialization

Comment: client.connect() returns true so I can confirm the connection is established @SergeyRomanov

Comment: Where do you set the address od device?